# Can not use unicode string in django template

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I used "BỘ MÔN TOÁN" string in django template it raised error **"'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 569: invalid continuation byte"**. But when I use "BO MON TOAN" string, it does'nt raise error. So, I used vietnamese in template and this is my code:

```
{% extends "site_base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block body_base %}
     <div class="subject-box-title">
         BỘ MÔN TOÁN
     </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is error in my project:
[image]

What's happening in my project. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: @zetysz please don't recommend that randomly; it has nothing whatsoever to do with the problem (it is for determining the encoding of literals *within the same file*).

Comment: Try resaving your template in `utf-8`. There has to be such an option in your IDE or text editor.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the error message? Rather than posting a screenshot, click on "Switch to copy-and-paste view" and paste the result here.

Comment: Hi all, follow @pythad 's way: "Try resaving your template in utf-8", I can do that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define into your HTML tag!

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and then try to o/p the string.

Comment: thank you. I use your solutions in other my case. It seems every good.

Answer (score 1):

To debug the issue follow following steps:

1. In your python files, declare the encoding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
2. In your base html `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`