# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError when saving Cyrillian

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

`DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at 0x7f41203ed790> (<class 'django.forms.boundfield.BoundField'>)`

```
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/dss/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/dss/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/dss/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 326, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/dss/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 995, in render
    bits.append(force_text(bit))
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/dss/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 88, in force_text
    raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)
```

I don't know what is the reason for this.

I added # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- to all python files.

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976921/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xc5-in-position-35       - you probably need to add __unicode__ to your models if you're using model-based forms or use @python_2_unicode_compatible    decorator   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741754/python-2-unicode-compatible-error

Comment: I had unicode, but in template I need to explicitly call it. Can you tell me why? Following code doesn't work in template str(instance)+'!!!', but this works: unicode(instance)+'!!!'

Comment: The template tag does not know how to convert using python operators  - you have to do any conversions in either python handling your code or declare in html as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866503/can-not-use-unicode-string-in-django-template